# Tableau - Dynamic Reference line that changes based filter selection

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

Instead of repeating the entire question, this is *exactly* what I'm trying to accomplish:

https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T00000VBxdgSAD/dynamic-reference-line-that-changes-based-filter-selection

I have two data sources.

One of which creates a visualization along with filter of the following values:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

and another which contains the value I want the reference line to be set at based on the filter selection:

```
selection value
foo        10
bar        20
baz        50
```

Where a filter selection of `foo` would set a reference line at `10`, `bar` at `20`, `baz` at `50`, `foo` and `bar` at `30`, `foo` and `baz` at `60`, `bar` and `baz` at `70`, etc.

Is there some combination of parameters or calculated fields I can use to show the appropriate reference line value from data source 2 based on the filter selection from data source 1?

Edit: Grammar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1. You can point a reference line to a calculated field.
2. You can create a [dual axis viz](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/multiple_measures.htm) with bars and a dynamic line chart.

### Using a Calculated Field as a Reference Line

First, map your values. *We'll use this for a dual axis chart as well.*

Create a calculated field `[ref_mapping]` that will map the values you need:

```
CASE [director]
WHEN 'foo' THEN 10 //if your [value] column already has the number you need ***AND is already mapped to your directors***, you can replace 10 with [value]
WHEN 'bar' THEN 20 //[value]
...
END
```

Second, make your values dynamically change based off the view filter.

Next take a windowed sum of `[ref_mapping]` so it only calculates based off what the view is filtered to (*This assumes `[director]` is in the filter pane*).

Make a new calculated field called `[dynamic_ref]`:

```
WINDOW_SUM([ref_mapping], FIRST(), LAST())
```

Now go to analytics pane and add a reference line by dragging it to your viz. Edit the reference line by selecting the value from drop down. The field `[dynamic_ref]` should now available to use as reference line.

### Create a Dual Axis Bar Chart

- Bring the two measure you wish to compare to the rows shelf(say `SUM([Sales])` and  `SUM([ref_mapping])`).
- Right click one of your measure pills and select dual axis.
- In your Marks Pane make sure *Bar* is selected for the data you are comparing the reference value against (such as `SUM([Sales])`) and *Line* is selected for the actual reference values (such as `SUM([ref_mapping]`).

### Helpful Links

- [Adjustable Reference Line](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NFhZfDmgVeE)
- [Add calculated field as reference line](https://www.edureka.co/community/42426/add-reference-line-from-calculated-field)
- [Table Calculations in Tableau](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_tablecalculation.htm)
- [Understanding view and expression level of detail implications in Tableau](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_replication.htm)

Comment: First off, thanks for this answer. However, my reference line values will change quarterly, ie foo won't always be 10, which is why I created that second data source (it is a sql query that will keep these reference values up to date). Is there a way around this without hardcoding these reference line values?

Comment: @bismo of course! when connecting the data sources, [logically link your tables with a data blend](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/multiple_connections.htm) (most likely on `[director]` or `[director_id]`) and just replace 10 with `[value]`.

Comment: Awesome! When creating the window function `WINDOW_SUM([ref_mapping], FIRST(), LAST())` I get the error 'Cannot mix aggregate and non-aggregate arguments with this function'... Used the exact function you have in your answer as well. Any ideas? I set yp `ref_mapping` with hardcoded values first just to get something working before I try the data blending step.

Comment: This is [one of the most common errors in Tableau](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/error-cannot-mix-aggregate-and-non-aggregate-arguments-with-this-function-when-creating-a-calculated-field), check out that link on ways to resolve it. I cannot test for what you have aggregated or not in my head, I apologize. As for the blend, are you bringing in two different data sources or two different tables or views from the same source?

Comment: I was able to fix the error by adding a sum to `[ref_mapping]`, like this `WINDOW_SUM([ref_mapping], FIRST(), LAST())`, but now when I create a reference line, I don't have the option to select this `[ref_mapping]` as it is a calculated field and note a parameter. How can I use `[dynamic_ref]` as a reference line?

Comment: If I drag `[dynamic_ref]` to the `Detail` portion of the all marks card, I can use it as a reference line but it is not appearing anywhere. Edit: When I add a "fill below" to this reference line, the entire chart is filled, meaning my reference line is way high up somehow? The values I have set for it wouldn't make that possible, though

Comment: @bismo if I may ask, what is stopping you from using just using `[value]` as a reference line? Also for the above issue, `[dynamic_ref]` may need to be fixed to the director level. Say `{FIXED [director] : [dynamic_ref]}` or `{FIXED [director] : MAX([dynamic_ref])}`

Comment: I didn't use `[value]` as a reference line because you mentioned to use `[dynamic_ref]` as a reference line: "The field `[dynamic_ref]` should now available to use as reference line". Also, I'm not sure where to change `[dynamic_ref]` to a director.

Comment: Alright, I now have a reference line that updates according to filter selection, but each category in my filter is assigned a value of 6.6 million instead of what I have assigned to them in `[ref_mapping]`... any idea why this might be?

Comment: @bismo its probably summing every occurrence, see if you can switch `SUM` to `MAX`